A step in a proof of Erdos's lower bound for R(k, k)
Being in my 40s, I recently have been going back to romantic periods of my life. I am old now.
What happened the most romantic in my life was Paul Erdos. I got interested in math because of him. And math keeps enlightening my life even when I am jobless sometimes.
My most interest in math is actually analytic number theory, which has a different taste from Erdos's main field, combinatorics.
To help me pursue my romance, please give me advice on my question. I am a complete layman and extremely bad at combinatorics; analytic number theory is, I guess, much easier because I don't encounter big gaps in logic from step to step.
So the question is as follows.
Looking for what book may be good for having a bit of taste of Erdos's work, I found the book by Vasek Chvatal, titled The discrete mathematical charms of Paul Erdos.
The book is doing good so far for reminding me of my passion for Erdos.
I have overcome some difficulties, but now I am stuck.
Say R(k,k) is the Ramsey number of k and k. I don't know how it's called.
The theorem is
$R(k, k) > 2^{k/2}$.
In the terminology of the book, a colouring is bad if it creates a red complete graph of order k or of blue, or both, and let B denote the set of all bad colourings.
Let $\Omega$ be the set of all colourings of the complete graph of n vertices.
Let $n \leq 2^{k /2}$.
Then, the book says all of sudden that
the theorem is equivalent to
$|B| < |\Omega|$.
I somewhat am guessing that the property of the number R(k, k) should be used in deducing this equivalent statement, because if there are R(k, k) vertices, we are guaranteed that each colouring is bad.
But actually, I have no idea how this relates the inequality of the theorem to the latter one.
Please help me on this.
I guess the rest of the proof of the theorem in the book sounds straightforward to me. If you have time, you can give me the whole proof of this theorem here too.
Thanks for your time.

I will address the specific question you mentioned. I think the nature of other difficulties one may find in the proof will be more technical and so it may be better to post them as separate questions.
Anyway,  $R(k,k)$ is the smallest number $M$ for which any (red,blue)-coloring of the edges of the complete graph of $M$ vertices is bad. A simple but key observation is that if $m>R(k,k)$, then any such coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_m$ on $m$ vertices is bad as well (because we already find a monochromatic copy of $K_k$ by looking at any $R(k,k)$ vertices of the $m$ we have available).
Ok. To show that $R(k,k)>2^{k/2}$ is the same as showing that if $n\le 2^{k/2}$, then $n<R(k,k)$. In turn, to show that $n<R(k,k)$ is the same as showing that there is a coloring of the edges of $K_n$ that is not bad, which is the same as showing that there are more colorings than bad colorings, that is $|B|<|\Omega|$:
If $n<R(k,k)$, by minimality of $R(k,k)$, it is clear that $|B|<|\Omega|$. If $n=R(k,k)$, by definition $|B|=|\Omega|$. If $n>R(k,k)$, the comment in my second paragraph shows that $|B|=|\Omega|$ as well.

Yep. And I recall that the author of the book was talking about this technique of proving by noting strict inequality in earlier chapter.
